# a user has_many :reviews twice

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I think I have to make a self-referential association (ok,after reading a comment, I guess it's not self-referential, but the naming problem still exists) for my Rails app but I can't figure out how I should set it up (even after watching a Railscast on the concept).  In my app, a user can write a review of another user. Therefore, a user has_many :reviews in the sense that they have written many reviews. I've coded that below...

```
User.rb

has_many :reviews  (a user can review many professionals)


Review.rb

belongs_to :user
```

In the migration I am doing

```
rails g resource Review user_id:integer review:text
```

My question is, since I've already said, User.rb has_many :reviews and Review.rb belongs_to :review for the user doing the reviews, how would I add the associations for the user that is being reviewed? Also, what would I add to the migration to contain the id of the user-to-be-reviewed?

Comment: This isn't self-referential at all. Users reference reviews. Reviews reference users. A "self-referential" review would be if a user referenced a user or a review referenced a review.

Comment: ok, so it's not self-referential, but the problem still remains. a user has_many :reviews (people he's reviewed) and a user has_many :reviews (been reviewed multiple times) how do I deal with that?

Comment: @meagar I updated the title based on your comment. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `reviews` table is really a many-to-many table, where both keys point to the `users` table.

First, you need to decide on key names; I'd suggest "author" and "subject", as "reviewer" and "reviewee" are potentially confusing.

You'd set your models up thusly:

```
class User
  has_many :authored_reviews, class_name: "Review", foreign_key: "author_id"


class Review    
  belongs_to :author, class_name: "User"
  belongs_to :subject, class_name: "User"
```

I think the piece you're missing is that you want to see who your users have reviewed? For that, you'd add another `has_many` to your User model and specify the other `foreign_key`. The hardest part is the name; the verbiage would be "a user is the subject of many reviews", but "referencing_reviews" might suffice. I think I might simply choose "reviews":

```
class User
  # Reviews this user has written
  has_many :authored_reviews, class_name: "Review"

  # Reviews others have written about this user
  has_many :reviews, class_name: "Review", foreign_key: "subject_id"
```

Another strategy might be to treat reviews like messages, and call your associations `sent_reviews` and `received_reviews`, or `written_reviews` and `received_reviews`. Naming can be difficult, but it's important to get it reasonably correct. It's a big part of writing maintainable software.

To generate your migration for the `reviews` table, use `references` instead of `integer` for foreign keys, which will set up the `_id` postfix and an index for you:

```
$ rails g model Review author:references subject:references
```

This will give you `author_id` and `subject_id` columns.

Comment: thanks, it's actually more important to see which users have been reviewed (rather than who did the reviews). I'm not sure how this code in User--- has_many :reviews, class_name: "Review" -- makes clear whether it's reviews a user has done, or reviews a user has been subject to?

Comment: @BrainLikeADullPencil See update; my early revisions weren't finished.

Comment: ok, thanks, it works. I'm having to put in the author and subject_id in a hidden field. Usually with associations, the user_id is inserted automatically into the db record, however, here author_id and subject_id were blank until i added hidden fields.